# Google plus sign in button not rendered when online

Tags: javascript, web, google-plus

I'm developing a community site for my new mobile game and I'm trying to add the google plus sign in flow to it.

---

**Steps taken during implementation:**

-> Followed [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button) google developers tutorial

HTML button code:

```
     <span id="signinButton">
        <span
            class="g-signin"
            data-callback="onSignInCompleted"
            data-clientid="<myID>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
        </span>
    </span>
```

Javascript load code: (just before body closure)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();
</script>
```

---

**The problem:**

-> The implementation works fine in localhost

-> The implementation doesn't work online (i.e. uploaded on the server)

---

**Online page strange behavior:**

-> The button doesn't get rendered

-> The signed callback doesn't get called

---

**My web application OAuth 2.0 javascript origins:**

```
https://fcouceiro.com
https://www.fcouceiro.com
http://www.fcouceiro.com
http://fcouceiro.com
http://meatify:8888
```

I'm currently using fcouceiro.com as origin, but the idea is to use meatify.fcouceiro.com subdomain after this problem is solved.

---

UPDATE: after some experiments i've found that sometimes (like the first time you're visiting the page) it does get rendered (the button). So I'm thinking the problem clould be the script being loaded after the html for instance. As I'm using the jQuery load function to load an html page that contains the sign in button. And than the onload gets called and the script tries to find my button but it isn't available. What do you think?

You can find my page here:
http://fcouceiro.com

APPy coding!

Comment: This may be a hostname problem. I'm not at all familiar with G+, but I do know that often this happens especially when you're on Localhost

Comment: Ghostery is also NOT blocking anything, so it is likely not finding the Google button.

Comment: What do yo suggest? I've included many hostname possibilities in my project javascript origins.

Comment: did you mind the "https" vs "http" ? Did you "one line = one url" ?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit my question to include it!

Comment: Try putting the script above the HTML for the button

Comment: No success either. I've been also playing with the data-cockiepolicy, but with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know the callback doesn't fire if the button doesn't render in the first place? I just tried it and got the JS error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined` in `filterUserMail`.

Comment: I knew it because this API logs you in automatically even without clicking the button. But apparently it did got called! Because you're reporting some error associated to a method that gets called in this callback. I dont get that JS error. I mean, this is a bit weird, it does work well in localhost. Thanks for your comment @abraham. Have any ideas to try?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on your browser's JavaScript console? Sometimes this can help.

Comment: The main problem is precisely that! ;) No erros are thrown. Don't know what to do right now. I've emailed my domain name provider regarding this issue. Without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok guys. Problem solved! Thanks for your help. Here is the solution (complex one...):

Just make sure that the javascript for the google + sign in button is loaded after the button is "loaded" (if you use the html render method). My problem was that my sign in button was loaded by jQuery load function into a div and sometimes this function takes some time to execute. Fortunately there is a callback argument in that function that I've set up to load my g+ js!

Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

To clarify the chosen answer:

The platform.js must be loaded before you render the sign-in button, for example in angularjs, you could simply use $timeout to wait for 1 sec.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who might get tangled with this,`data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"` might be the cause of your problems.

Just try clearing your cookies or setting `data-cookiepolicy="none"` while developing.

A more in depth description of date-cookiepolicy can be found here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference