# google sign-in button not rendering

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm trying to build a chrome extension (very new to extension programming). I want to use the google login button to authenticate users with their google accounts. I've been following many tutorials (and have done a lot of researching) such as this one https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin. i cant find any that have fixed the rendering problem. I'm getting this error, but not sure if it is the cause of my problem.

`message: "Invalid cookiePolicy"
stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy`

**My manifest.json file:**

**(Keys have been modified)**

```html
{ 
 "name": "Save My Pass",
 "version": "1.1",
 "description": "Create a useful tool that will help eliminate the worries of remembering and managing passwords by yourself.",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "author":"Austin Jerich",
 "permissions": ["identity", "storage", "https://*.google.com/"],

 "background":{
  "scripts": [
   "js/background.js"
  ],
  "persistent": false
 },
 
 "content_scripts": [{
  "js": ["js/oauth.js"],
  "matches": ["http://*/*"]
 }],
 
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",

 "browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "pages/home.html",
  "default_icon": "images/icon_48.png"
 },

 "icons": {
  "48": "images/icon_48.png"
 },

 "options_page": "pages/options.html",

 "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmeybG4Q1WXCLsMw0zPaBqi2f02sNSXEwDn8bH0G1TqqLtO0IRKXlXpRVYPiAP3vyeLya6VgjbXhSBI9JqqZxSJtjhK2iHUNEN2SHWG4KS6E5NqmsvpxoZCSWQBhx2omOfpggGTjbIKEgULJQLWEYmsvu6YAPdsbpB49sZ5A/x4udI1WecwYumWKgWB3oFSpwuvcEBeldMPvLCcRahIPC469zvAHFhHNhqQIDAQAB",


 "oauth2": {
  "client_id": "1976054582-cjejnq5eh1sci558rb0evq.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"]
 }
}
```

**The login.html file where the google sign-in button is located:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
 <!--<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>-->

 <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="1976054582-cjejnq5eh1sc58rb0evq.apps.googleusercontent.com">
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/oauth.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/default.css">
<style>
h2{
 text-align: center;
}

#submit{
 text-align: center;
}

#username, #password{
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
  <h2>SaveMyPass</h2>
  <!--<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"></input>
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"></input>-->
  <div id="submit"><input type="submit" id="btn-login" value="Login"></input></div>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

**The oauth.js file i was working with earlier (not sure if relevant or not)**

```html
 window.onload=function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn-login').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("click login")
  chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
   let init = {
   method: 'GET',
   async: true,
   headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   'contentType': 'json'
        };
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: 1) The error message says your CSP has `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` (which would be wrong) but the posted code is correct - did you reload the extension on chrome://extensions page? 2) Unrelated to the problem per se, but "content_scripts" can only list local files in your extension package, not remote files, and it's only to have that script run alongside web pages, which is probably not what you need. 3) I would expect existing examples for this exact task to be somewhere on the web, try searching more.

Comment: @w i modified the content and background scripts and changed the oauth.js file. that got rid of the script load error. but did not get the google sign-in button to appear (which was my original problem).

Comment: @wOxxOm I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117659/google-plus-sign-in-button-not-rendered-when-online. a solution was to render the button after loading the JS file, but i dont think this is my problem. i did a lot of searching, but couldnt find anything that can get it to render.